# disable automount in fedora

Tags: usb, fedora, fedora-14, hal

I have edited `/etc/hal/fdi/policy/prefrences.fdi`

```
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
  <device>
    <match key="storage.policy.should_mount" bool="true">
      <merge key="storage.policy.should_mount" type="bool">false</merge>
    </match>
    <match key="storage.automount_enabled_hint" bool="true">
      <merge key="storage.automount_enabled_hint" type="bool">false</merge>
    </match>
    <match key="storage.media_check_enabled" bool="true">
      <merge key="storage.media_check_enabled" type="bool">false</merge>
    </match>
    <match key="volume.policy.should_mount" bool="true">
      <merge key="volume.policy.should_mount" type="bool">false</merge>
    </match>
    <match key="volume.ignore" bool="false">
      <merge key="volume.ignore" type="bool">true</merge>
    </match>
  </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

but is does not help

also know I can use gconf for that but the user can chage his own gconf file. I want no one be able to mount a usb flash disk excpet me and some special users

Comment: GNOME does not use `hal` anymore; disk mounting is done by `udisks`, and can be controlled through PolicyKit.

Answer (score 0):

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false